# Debug pipeline code from IntelliJ?

Tags: debugging, jenkins, intellij-idea, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Is there some info on how to debug jenkins pipeline code using IntelliJ ? I'd like to be able to step through my pipeline code ...

Answer (score 0):

I looked for that too. I think is not possible yet.